# Timeout with apache QPID

Tags: java, amqp, qpid

I have a problem with an application in Java.
This application uses Apache QPid broker (6.0.1) to send messages.

I run it on 2 computers : the computer I use to work, and the 1 we use to test application before we give it to the client.

On my computer, there is no problem, the application send or receive messages.

The problem is we the other computer. I installed qpid the same way i did on mine : I extracted the .tar.gz, set $QPID_WORK to the working directory, and set ports i use with web management interface.
I tried it yesterday morning, and no problems, all works fine.

But after that, I stopped qpid (my boss asked me to show her how to start every components of the application) and since i can't send messages anymore.

I tried 2 applications :
The first one is the application I work on. The first thing it does is connect to qpid with JMX/RMI (with the apache API). But i have a timeout exception at this moment.

The second application is an app I did to test QPID and see how i can send a message. I also have a timeout exception when i try to send the message.

With the second application, QPID detect the connexion (and display it in web interface) but it doesn't create the queue or put message if it already exists.

I think this is a configuration problem (maybe access rights on a file?) but i'm not sure, and if i'm right, i can't find where is the problem.

I wanted to try to send the message from my computer on the qpid on test computer, but there are not on the same network, and i can't test that :(

Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong?

ps : i apologize for english mistakes, i'm french
ps 2 : i can't show you code exept the one i created to try qpid, but there is nothing really interesting (I took a big part of it from apache documentation with just a few modifications that work on my computer)

Comment: The connection with RMI being what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The connection with RMI makes a timeout like the message producer.
I found a solution :
the overflow on the exchange was set to 0 (unlimited) but if I change (like 10MO) it works without timeout.

But I still don't know if it's a qpid bug, or a problem with the computer, I'll try to find out with the system administrator and i'll post here if we find an answer if someone else have the same problem.